# Oauth authentification to Fitbit using httr

Tags: r, oauth, fitbit, httr

I'm trying to connect to the fitbit api using the [httr library](https://github.com/hadley/httr/).

Using the examples provided, I came up with the following code:

```
library(httr)

key <- '<edited>'
secret <- '<edited>'
tokenURL <- 'http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token'
accessTokenURL <- 'http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token'
authorizeURL <- 'https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize'

fbr <- oauth_app('fitbitR',key,secret)
fitbit <- oauth_endpoint(tokenURL,authorizeURL,accessTokenURL)

token <- oauth1.0_token(fitbit,fbr)
sig <- sign_oauth1.0(fbr,
    token=token$oauth_token,
    token_secret=token$oauth_token_secret
)
```

I get the *Authentication complete.* message from httr, but trying to access the api then throws an error message

```
GET("http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/2012-08-29.json", sig)
Response [http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/2012-08-29.json]
  Status: 401
  Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
{"errors":[{"errorType":"oauth","fieldName":"oauth_access_token","message":"Invalid signature or token '<edited>' or token '<edited>'"}]}
```

Any clue about what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the httr library, that uses curlEscape for encoding paramaters while the OAuth 1.0 specifications requires percent encoding (see [this page](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#encoding_parameters)).

Replacing calls to curlEscape with curlPercentEncode solves the issue!

many thanks to @mark-s for his help.

Comment: Could you please expand the answer by giving an example code of how to "replace call to curlEscape with curlPercentEncode"?

Comment: Would you care to explain what this means? (Although I'm not sure if that's still relevant since implementation of `httr` seems to have changed).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I notice is that your call to get the signature is slightly different than the httr examples. The httr examples are:

```
sig <- sign_oauth1.0(myapp, token$oauth_token, token$oauth_token_secret)
```

While your code is:

```
sig <- sign_oauth1.0(fbr,
    token=token$oauth_token,
    token_secret=token$oauth_token_secret
)
```

Do you need the "token=" and "token_secret=" in your code?

Comment: Just tried for the sake of it, but it made no difference: anyway, using named arguments should not make a difference? But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Can you post the verbose request with the headers included?

Comment: Here is the http header: OAuth oauth%5Fconsumer%5Fkey=\"<edited>\", oauth%5Fnonce=\"ImkQ6g3HO0\", oauth%5Fsignature=\"<edited>\", oauth%5Fsignature%5Fmethod=\"HMAC%2DSHA1\", oauth%5Ftimestamp=\"1346655744\", oauth%5Ftoken=\"<edited>\", oauth%5Fversion=\"1%2E0\" does this help?

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm sitting behind a proxy: although I tried it on a different computer and got the same problem, could this be a reason?

Comment: after much looking around it turns out that the oauth_signature was the problem (as was indeed reported by the API) - see my answer below