# strsplit error when attempting to access Fitbit with ROAuth

Tags: r, oauth, fitbit

I am attempting to access the fitbit API using ROAuth but keep falling at the first hurdle.

Here is my code:

```
library(ROAuth)

reqURL <- "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize"
cKey <- "xxxxx"
cSecret <- "xxxxx"

credentials <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=cKey,
                            consumerSecret=cSecret,
                            requestURL=reqURL,
                            accessURL=accessURL,
                            authURL=authURL)
credentials$handshake()
```

Running this gives the following rather cryptic error:

```
Error in strsplit(response, "&") : non-character argument
```

Any suggestions, greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would do something like `options(error = recover)` and try to evaluate `response` expression in its called environment.

Comment: response
  [1] 6f 61 ...
[100] 75 74 ... 64 3d 74 72 75 65
attr(,"Content-Type")
                                                                charset 
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"                             "UTF-8"

Comment: That's an edited extract of `response`. Not sure what to make of that!

Comment: You might find it easier to use the OAuth support in httr.

Comment: I seem to be getting a bit further with `httr`. I've based my code on some of the github demos, but when it tries to authenticate in the browser, the page that comes up says "This page is no longer valid. It looks like you provided an invalid token or someone already used the token you provided. Please return to the site or application which sent you to this page and try again." I've tried resetting the keys to no avail.

Comment: I discovered the problem...I was using ouath2 not oauth1. [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212958/oauth-authentification-to-fitbit-using-httr/12218175) sorted me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @[hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) rather than solving the `ROAuth` problem, I have switched to using the `httr` package instead. The code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212958/oauth-authentification-to-fitbit-using-httr/12218175) worked for me.