# OAuth with httr package and twitter API v1.1

Tags: r, twitter, httr, roauth

I'm trying to follow the demo in the httr package to authorize myself with twitter. However, using the code in the demo only produces this error:

```
Response [https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json]
  Status: 410
  Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

What in the code would need to be changed to allow it to work with Twitter API v1.1 (note that the key and token below are from the demo, but I use my own to produce the error above)?

I've also tried using the Roauth package, but it gives me the same error as here: [strsplit error when attempting to access Fitbit with ROAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882011/strsplit-error-when-attempting-to-access-fitbit-with-roauth)

```
myapp <- oauth_app("twitter", key = "TYrWFPkFAkn4G5BbkWINYw")

sig <- sign_oauth1.0(myapp,
  token = "69133574-FZ9GJlJ57V0SVdNAzo71mQZSUrpUbiJZBVpDmbYkd",
  token_secret = Sys.getenv("TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"))

GET("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json", sig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ... `GET("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json", sig)` instead (substitute `1` by `1.1`).