# What function in R package httr performs request and imports activities from Fitbit API?

Tags: r, api, httr, fitbit

I have used the `httr` package in R to obtain access to the Fitbit API, but I'm uncertain on which function I should use to extract activities from the API.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Please provide example code with the function.

---

I believe I have found one possible answer.

Using the setup inputs from this stackoverflow answer/question: [httr fitbit API question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212958/oauth-authentification-to-fitbit-using-httr).

Once I gained authorization I then used the `httr` function `GET`.

```
GET(url= paste0("http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/2013-06-07.json"), config=sig)
```

In the config argument, the `sig` variable was derived from the answer/question linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
activities <- GET(url = "http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/2013-06-07.json",
                  config=sig)
content(activities)
```

That will give you the results in a list from which you can more easily extract what you are after.